# Calculating Social Media Score for URLs

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter

I am trying to create a ranking system for URLs that are fetched from RSS Feeds.

I tried to get FB likes or Twitter shares for URLs but I dont see consistent result.

Instead of doing that by myself, is there any 3rd party library which does such calculation?
What are the best practices on finding share counts for URLs on Twitter + Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

What inconsistency are you seeing?

You should be able to score them by matching the URL to, for example, a tweet and then scoring based on its retweet_count value. The important step is determining what you want your scoring to be based on.

If it's time sensitive then look at the Reddit or Hacker News algorithms that use number of votes (in your case, shares and retweets) and the time since they were posted. That way newer tweets would score higher but older tweets with many retweets would still remain high (reflects popularity).